# Do this dispose the child objects or not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clr, dispose, idisposable

I have two classes, say class `MyFirstClass` and `MyAnotherClass` , `MyAnotherClass` is implementing IDiposable interface.

```
public class MyFirstClass
{
   public string xyz{get;set;} ..... and so on
}


public class MyAnotherClass : IDisposable
{
   private readonly MyFirstClass objFc = new MyFirstClass();
   public static  void MyStaticMethod()
   {
        var objOfFirstClass = new MyFirstClass();
        // something with above object
   }

   public void MyNonStaticMethod()
   {
      // do something with objFc
   }

   #region Implementation of IDisposable
    .... my implementations
   #endregion
}
```

Now I have one more class where I am calling `MyAnotherClass` , something like this

```
using(var anotherObj = new MyAnotherClass())
{
   // call both static and non static methods here, just for sake of example.
   // some pretty cool stuffs goes here... :)
}
```

So I would like to know, should I worry about the cleanup scenario of my objects? Also, what will happen to my `ObjFC` (inside non static) and the `objOfFirstClass` (inside static).

AFAIK, using will take care of everything...but i need to know more...

Comment: The class `MyFirstClass` does not implement `IDisposable`. Is this by intent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`objOfFirstClass` is a local variable in a method. It will be eligible for garbage collection once the method is exited. It won't be disposed as such because it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

`objFc` will be eligible for garbage collection when its parent object goes out of scope. Again, this is nothing to do with disposing it.

`Dispose`/`IDisposable` is used when there is clean up *other than simple memory management* to be done. The CLR handles cleaning up the memory for you using garbage collection. `using` is a nice way of ensuring that an object implementing `IDisposable` has its `Dispose` method called when you have finished with it - but if all you are after is memory management, you don't need to use it.

Comment: So, What if I am using static methods in a class that has IDisposable implemented and the class is no static . Static objects will available in memory after its usage or it will get carried out for garbage collection ????

Comment: Objects defined as static _fields_ would remain in memory, but local variables in static _methods_ will be eligible for collection once the method exits.

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` indicates that an object is using resources *other than managed memory*; for example, file handles. The `Dispose` method is supposed to handle the clean-up of these resources (and that's what your implementation should do).

Any CLR-native object (e.g. those in your example) is garbage collected by the CLR when no more references to it exist (more specifically, by a mechanism called the *garbage collector* or GC); `IDisposable` is unnecessary in these cases.

In order to make use of `IDisposable` you have to call `Dispose` yourself (or use `using`, which is just syntactic sugar). It isn't called automatically by the GC.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any magic behind `IDisposable` except that `using` calls the `Dispose` method.

As the class `MyFirstClass` does not implement `IDisposable`, there is no need to worry about instances of this class - they should not have anything to dispose.

If you have fields or variables that need to be disposed, you have to call `Dispose`. Additionally, you should implement a destructor that calls the `Dispose` method, as [the reference proposes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx):

```
~MyClass() {
    Dispose(false);
}
```

Where the boolean parameter specifies that fields should *not* be disposed, in this case. For details, see the linked msdn page.

Comment: An MSDN link in English would be better on an English speaking site... ;)

Answer (score -1):

`IDispose` disposes the class `MyAnotherClass`. This means that local variables of the `MyFirstClass` object are pointing to nothing. Therefore, they are reclaimed once the garbage collector runs.

Comment: The eligibility for garbage collection is based on variables going out of scope. Dispose has nothing to do with it.